# What is the difference between local and remote SonarQube Eclipse Plugin analysis?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sonarqube, sonarlint

As I understand Eclipse Plugin for SonarQube has two options: local and remote analysis.

What is the difference between them?

Should we install Sonar Server locally to run local analysis?

Will we see results of remote analisis in remote Sonar Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by using the good wording : the SonarQube Eclipse Plugin is dead and now there is SonarLint for Eclipse : http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html. This Eclipse plugin supports two modes :

1. The "Standalone mode": which is the default one and which doesn't require to have any SonarQube server running.
2. The "Connected mode" : which can be activated on-demand to make SonarLint using locally the same rules and analyzers that are used remotely by the SonarQube server to analyse the same project.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand correctly that the "Standalone mode" uses default rules and we cannot manage them (enable, disable, add custom rules etc.)?

Comment: Your understanding is indeed correct @user3186861 !